# How can i show a different activity till handler (for 1 minute) is running, in bottomnavigationview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, handler

I am showing a notification badge in bottomNavView, for 2 minutes after coming to an activity. I am removing that badge after 2 minutes.
But i want to show a different activity for those 2(handler) minutes.
Scenario is : in bottomnavView click on third tab---> then click a button inside that fragment---> Anotheractivity--->after coming back to dashboard, badge visible for two minutes.
These two minutes i want to show the Anotheractivity on clicking on third tab. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

```
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.firsttab:

                    fragment = firsttabFragment.newInstance();
                    addButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    break;

                case R.id.secondTab:

                    fragment = secondTabFragment.newInstance();
                    addButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;

                case R.id.thirdTab:
                    fragment = thirdTabFragment.newInstance();
                    addButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;


after coming back to anotherActivity, here is the badge i am showing for two minutes




   Utils.showBadge(DashBoardActivity.this, navView, R.id.thirdTab, "");
   final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Utils.removeBadge(navView, R.id.findatm);
            }
        }, 100000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the on click listener of your third tab when you click the button of your fragment. Then in the handler reset the on click listener of your third tab to the original. This way for the 2 minutes clicking on the third tab will take you to the "otherActivity" and after the 2 minutes has passed clicking on the third tab will show the original fragment.

Edit:

Here is some code:

```java
//make a variable in your main activity
 public boolean twoMinutesActivated = false;

 //in your fragment
 fragmentButton.setOnClickListener(...){
    ...
    getActivity.setTwoMinutesActivated(true);
 }

 //in your onNavigationItemSelected
 case R.id.thirdTab:
          if(!twoMinutesActivated){
                fragment = thirdTabFragment.newInstance();
                addButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }else{
                //launch second activity
          }
          break;

 //in the handler
     @Override
        public void run() {
            Utils.removeBadge(navView, R.id.findatm);
            twoMinutesActivated = false;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you sir @Adonis320 did the same thing but its not working :(

Comment: Does anything change at all ?

Comment: Try debugging the problem:   getActivity.setTwoMinutesActivated(true); //Log.i("debugging", getActivity().twoMinutesActivated+"") and after the case R.id.thirdTab //Log.i("debugging", twoMinutesActivated+""); try seeing if the values of the boolean change at all